# Why does my GPU refuse to accept a shared memory configuration without emitting an error?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

Consider the program below.

It gets a CUDA device's current shared memory bank size configuration; sets it to another value; then gets it again. Unfortunately, this is the output:

```
The reported shared memory bank size for device 0 is: 4 bytes.
Will now set the shared memory bank size for device 0 to: 8 bytes.
After setting shared memory bank size to 8 bytes,
the reported shared memory bank size for device 0 is: 4 bytes.
```

My question: Why does this happen? Specifically,

- Do some CUDA GPUs simply ignore this setting? If so, why isn't an error returned when setting the bank configuration?
- Does my program simply have a bug, perhaps?
- Is it because I use both runtime-API and driver-API calls?

Notes:

- I've removed most of the error checking for readability, but you'll need to trust me that I do actually check for errors.
- I'm running this on an GTX 1050 Ti Boost, CUDA 11.4, driver 470.57.02, on a Devuan GNU/Linux Chimaera.

```c++
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

const char* bank_size_descriptions[] = {"default", "4 bytes", "8 bytes" };
const char* bank_size_description(CUsharedconfig config) { return bank_size_descriptions[config]; }


int main()
{
    int device_id { 0 };
    CUcontext top_of_context_stack;
    CUsharedconfig bs_config;
    CUcontext primary_context_handle;
    CUresult status;

    cudaSetDevice(0);
    cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain(&primary_context_handle, device_id);
    cuCtxGetCurrent(&top_of_context_stack);
    assert(top_of_context_stack == primary_context_handle);
    cuCtxGetSharedMemConfig(&bs_config);

    std::cout
        << "The reported shared memory bank size for device "
        << device_id << " is: " << bank_size_description(bs_config) << ".\n";
    auto new_bs_config =
        (bs_config == CU_SHARED_MEM_CONFIG_FOUR_BYTE_BANK_SIZE) ?
        CU_SHARED_MEM_CONFIG_EIGHT_BYTE_BANK_SIZE :
        CU_SHARED_MEM_CONFIG_FOUR_BYTE_BANK_SIZE;
    std::cout
        << "Will now set the shared memory bank size for device "
        << device_id << " to: " << bank_size_description(new_bs_config) << ".\n";

    status = cuCtxSetSharedMemConfig(new_bs_config);
    assert(status == CUDA_SUCCESS);

    cuCtxGetSharedMemConfig(&bs_config);

    if (bs_config != new_bs_config) {
        std::cerr
            << "After setting shared memory bank size to " << bank_size_description(new_bs_config)
            << ",\nthe reported shared memory bank size for device "
            << device_id << " is: " << bank_size_description(bs_config) << '.' << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Comment: `This function will do nothing on devices with fixed shared memory bank size.` I would not expect an error in this case.

Comment: @AbatorAbetor: I was sure I was going to get a `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE` for a specific bank size that's not the fixed bank size. Anyway, can you make this an answer please?

Answer (score 3):

The [CUDA driver api documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__CTX.html#group__CUDA__CTX_1g2574235fa643f8f251bf7bc28fac3692) states the following.

`This function will do nothing on devices with fixed shared memory bank size.`

I think that in this case "doing nothing" is successful and thus no error code is returned.